# Python and PySide: Variable values reset when calling functions from another file

Tags: python, qt, pyside, qt-designer, praw

I've been writing this python script which basically sets your windows wallpaper background through reddit links and specific variables you set, like links from hot/top all time/etc. and i'm writing a GUI with PySide for it, currently i have 3 files.

- The ui file generated by QtDesigner output_ui.py
- Another file that interacts with the generated ui file [output.py](http://pastie.org/10604803)
- And the script that runs everything and sets the wallpaper [WallDit.py](http://pastie.org/10604828)

When i run the output.py file, set the values inside the GUI everything works correctly, the values are set fine, but when i click the start button and the script executes (WallDit.py) and calls the functions from output.py the variable values get reset to the default values (i.e. i set to "Wallpapers", it gets set back to the default "Wallpaper+Wallpapers").

For instance when i call this function from the 1st file, the subreddit line text value gets set back to default, no the one that is actually displayed on the GUI:

```
def handle_subreddit_line(self):
    print("subreddit line in output.py: " + self.subreddit_line.text())
    return self.subreddit_line.text()
```

Calling the function code:

```
def get_subreddit_name():
    test = MainWindow()
    print("test: " + test.handle_subreddit_line())
    subreddit = MainWindow().handle_subreddit_line()
    return subreddit
```

Note: When i change the values, say of the subreddit_name line the signal gets sent and the correct value outputs, the issue starts when the function gets called from the 1st file.

**Update:** If i call the function anywhere, the value still gets reset to the default

```
def handle_start_btn(self):
    if self.start_btn.isDown:
        print("Button pressed")
    print("inside function: " + MainWindow().handle_subreddit_line())
    import WallDit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `WallDit.py`, you initialize FIVE new windows. Which means you have five new text boxes. In order to fix your problem, you need to use a single instance, the one you create in `output.py`. For example, you can delete `main()` in `WallDit.py`, make `set_wallpaper` and other functions take a `window` argument, and do something like this:

```
def handle_start_btn(self):
    WallDit.set_wallpaper(self)
```

(move the `import` line to the top of the file, since WallDit will not execute anything on import now and it’s good practice to keep all imports there)

*edit: of course, you need to pass the `window` around and use it instead of `MainWindow()`.*